# PowerApps Newbie: Edit An Existing Dropdown on a Published PowerApps Form

Tags: drop-down-menu, powerapps

I have a published PowerApps form. In it is a dropdown field listing the applications used by my organization. How do I edit this dropdown to add additional values?

[image: Dropdown: Applications Impacted]

Answer (score 0):

From PowerApps...

1. Click on `View`
2. Then click `Data sources`
3. Click the 3 dots next to the Sharepoint list
4. Click "Edit data"

- This will take you to the Sharepoint list

From here, edit/create/delete the choices.